# How do i report in a proper way the progress of a files images convertion using a backgroundworker?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private int FilesNamesCounter = 0;
        private String FileName = "";
        private List<string> myGifs = new List<string>();
        private bool cancelop = false;
        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker bgw = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
            int Counter = 0;
            int percentage = 0;
            int total = allfiles.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < allfiles.Count; i++)
            {
                if (bgw.CancellationPending == true)
                {
                    pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
                    pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.Weather_Michmoret;
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    makeGif = false;
                    cancelop = true;
                    timer1.Stop();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    timer1.Start();
                    Counter += 1;
                    // calculating percentage and report it
                    percentage = Counter * 100 / total;
                    bgw.ReportProgress(percentage);
                    converttogif();
                }


            }
            if (makeGif == true)
            {
                FilesNamesCounter += 1;
                unfreez.MakeGIF(myGifs, outputfile + FilesNamesCounter + ".gif", 80, true);
            }
            bgw.ReportProgress(100);
            e.Result = allfiles;
        }
```

Convertion method:

```
private void converttogif()
    {
        DirectoryInfo dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(selectedfilesdirectoryName);
        FileInfo[] gifFileInfo = dirinfo.GetFiles("*.gif");
        Image gifImage;
        for (int i = 0; i < allfiles.Count; i++)
        {
            FileName = allfiles[i];
            gifImage = Image.FromFile(gifFileInfo[i].FullName);
            gifImage.Save(FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
            gifImage.Dispose();
            myGifs.Add(FileName);
        }
    }
```

Progress Changed event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        lblStatus.Text = "Processing......" + progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";

    }
```

Completed event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Cancelled == true))
        {
            button2.Enabled = false;
            lblStatus.Text = "Task Cancelled.";
        }

        else if (!(e.Error == null))
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Error while performing background operation.";
        }

        else
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Task Completed...";
            allfiles = (List<string>)e.Result;
            timer1.Stop();
            button1.Enabled = false;
            progressBar1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 211, 040);
            displaylastanimatedgif();
        }
    }
```

The problem is with the converttogif method in the DoWork event.
It will do loop in loop and will make each time the loop in the converttogif over and over again since i'm doing a loop over the images in the dowork already.

What i want to do is to report the progress in percentages of the convertion progress to the progressBar1. If i have in allfiles for example 285 files image to convert then convert them once and report on each file convert the progress in percentage to the progressBar so the whole convertion should be in the progressBar start from 0% to 100%  or maybe it's logical to start from 1% to 100%.

But the idea to report and show the convertion progress.

UPDATE

This is what i tried now:

```
private int FilesNamesCounter = 0;
        private String FileName = "";
        private List<string> myGifs = new List<string>();
        private bool cancelop = false;
        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker bgw = (BackgroundWorker)sender;            
            converttogif(bgw);            
            bgw.ReportProgress(100);
            e.Result = allfiles;
        }

        private void converttogif(BackgroundWorker bgw)
        {
            int Counter = 0;
            int percentage = 0;
            int total = allfiles.Count;
            DirectoryInfo dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(selectedfilesdirectoryName);
            FileInfo[] gifFileInfo = dirinfo.GetFiles("*.gif");
            Image gifImage;
            for (int i = 0; i < allfiles.Count; i++)
            {
                FileName = allfiles[i];
                gifImage = Image.FromFile(gifFileInfo[i].FullName);
                gifImage.Save(FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                gifImage.Dispose();
                myGifs.Add(FileName);
                Counter += 1;
                // calculating percentage and report it
                percentage = Counter * 100 / total;
                bgw.ReportProgress(percentage);
            }
        }



        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            lblStatus.Text = "Processing......" + progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";

        }


    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.Cancelled == true))
            {
                button2.Enabled = false;
                lblStatus.Text = "Task Cancelled.";
            }

            else if (!(e.Error == null))
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "Error while performing background operation.";
            }

            else
            {
                if (makeGif == true)
                {
                    FilesNamesCounter += 1;
                    unfreez.MakeGIF(myGifs, outputfile + FilesNamesCounter + ".gif", 80, true);

                }
                lblStatus.Text = "Task Completed...";
                allfiles = (List<string>)e.Result;
                timer1.Stop();
                button1.Enabled = false;
                progressBar1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 211, 040);
                displaylastanimatedgif();

            }
        }
```

The problem now is that it's getting to 99% and much before the end of the progressBar like 3/4 of the way but show 99% then it's waiting i used a breakpoint and it's getting to the completed event creating the animated gif then show 100% and the progressBar getting to the end.

How can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Easy, but not nice, way: pass the background worker to your converttogif function, and call `bgw.ReportProgress(percentage);` within the cicle.

A better solution is having your `converttoGif` be a part of a different class, raising its own "progress" event you can register to, and in the event handler call the `bgw.ReportProgress`

This would keep the gifconversion code isolated from the form and its backgroudworker, leaving the form the need to register for conversion class events.